# Why does ng-style call 2 times the function bound to it?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using ng-style to pass the styling in one of my directives.

Like so:

```
<my-component ng-style="test()" ng-model="message"></my-component>
```

And the directive:

```
myModule.directive('myComponent', function(mySharedService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: function($scope, $attrs, mySharedService) {
            $scope.test = function(){
                console.log(1)
            };
            $scope.$on('handleBroadcast', function() {
                $scope.message = 'Directive: ' + mySharedService.message;
            });
        },
        replace: true,
        template: '<input>'
    };
});
```

[JSFIDDLE That logs 2 times '1'](http://jsfiddle.net/njS2L/)

Why is the `test` function called 2 times?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once to get the value, again to see if it has changed. This is how watches work, and watches are processed every apply-digest cycle! This means watch expressions are called at least once per apply-digest cycle, and at most 10 times, which is the hard limit the Angular team enforces. Perhaps [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1iSG.png) clears it up a little! The arrow back from watch list to eval queue is the relevant bit.

HTH!

Comment: Hey thanks. One follow up question. In my application I noticed also logging without any change. Do the watches periodically do checks?

Comment: Every time a $digest loop runs, that function is going to be called.

Comment: As @JesusRodriguez said: every `$digest`! In JavaScript, a function's  value can only be determined by calling it, so it calls it every time to check!

Comment: @JimmyKane a little spamming maybe but maybe this helps: http://angular-tips.com/blog/2013/08/watch-how-the-apply-runs-a-digest/ Also #angularjs in freenode IRC helps with this basic questions.

Answer (score 3):

Just to elaborate on stevuu's answer -- Angular does a digest "cycle" which will be multiple synchronous digests until it gets a no-op where nothing changed. I think it would be a minimum of two iterations whenever anything changed. It would be one iteration when nothing changed. It could be several iterations though. Consider this:

Controller A:

```
$rootScope.$watch('a', function(val) {
   $rootScope.b = val + 1;
}
```

Controller B:

```
$rootScope.$watch('b', function(val) {
   $rootScope.c = val + 1;
}
```

Controller C:

```
$rootScope.$watch('c', function(val) {
   $rootScope.d = val + 1;
}
```

Now if you do a `$scope.$apply(function() { $rootScope.a = 5; })`

The end result should be that a == 5, b == 6, c == 7 and d == 8. Except you don't know what order the $watches run in, it's nondeterministic. So it could take like four passes to end up in its final state. And each "pass" calls every $watch defined in your app.

Comment: Thanks. The nondeterministic simplified more my problems.